# Есть ли практическая польза от языка Brainfuck?

Tags: brainfuck

Где и как он используется?

Comment: Название само за себя говорит.

Comment: матерный язык программирования для матерных целей))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Особой практической пользы от языка нет. В основном, используется на олимпиадах и соревнованиях по программированию.

Comment: Язык с матерным названием на олимпиадах? Господа понимают толк в извращениях!

Comment: а почему на олимпиадах и соревнованиях по программированию?
с чем связано такое применение?

Comment: F*ck каждый по-разному может перевести. Я бы например перевел, как "Долбаный мозг" или "Вынос мозга" =)

Answer (score 11):

Подобные языки не предназначены для практического применения. Разрабатываются исключительно ради шутки.

Answer (score 10):

Немного некропостинга, но правильного ответа не увидел.

Язык Brainfuck обладает фантастической простотой. Написать эмулятор Brainfuck на некотором языке - автоматически доказать его полноту по Тьюрингу. Полнота по Тьюрингу некоторого языка автоматически снимает множество вопросов, например, сразу ясно, что этот язык полностью равноценен любому другому, время работы программы является непредсказуемо долгим и т.д.

Answer (score 8):

По-моему, это чисто прикол. Ну, скажите: кому нужен язык, в котором для того, чтобы вывести на экран всеми нами любимый "hello world!" нужно fuck your brain for two hours и писать ТАКОЕ:

```
>+++++++++[<++++++++>-]<.>+++++++[<++++>-]<+.+++++++..+++.[-]>++++++++[<++++>-]
<.>+++++++++++[<+++++>-]<.>++++++++[<+++>-]<.+++.------.--------.[-]>++++++++[
<++++>-]<+.[-]++++++++++.
```

Лично я думаю, что это хорошее упражнение на внимательность и знание таблицы ASCII.
Разве по названию не понятно?

Comment: brainfuck - основоположник и бренд целого семейства "кошмарных" языков. Для любителей функционального программирования там есть "самый чистый язык фп" - unlambda. Основное назначение семейства - гимнастика для хвоста, пардон, для мозга.

Answer (score 5):

все зависит от того с какой целью создавался язык. если его назначение взрывать мозг разработчкику, то смею предположить, что польза от него есть

Answer (score 1):

Так как этот язык имеет очень простой синтаксис, то его можно обьяснить очень быстро (не факт, что программу после этого можно будет написать).
Именно по этой причине он хорош как язык для обученя написания компиляторов, интерпретаторов, изучения оптимизаций. Не с с++ компилятора ведь начинать . А знания пригодятся.

Много ли известно языков, полное описание которых влазит на кусочек бумажки и они являются тьюринг полными.

Comment: И что, у Scheme синтаксис сложнее? (Про форт вспоминать не будем).

Comment: синтаксис будет чуточку посложнее. Но вот компилятор-интерпретатор писать - это уже загадочнее.